# Destroy a PHP session on clicking a link

Tags: php, session, onclick, session-cookies, destroy

Is this code valid?

```
<a href="#" onclick="<?php session_destroy();?>">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No it is not a valid code. It will destroy the session at the time of loading the php page.

For destroying session on click you should write

```
<a href="logout.php" >Logout</a>
```

in logout.php

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: The session should be started before using session_destroy().

Answer (score 16):

Make a page called logout.php

Logout.php_***_*___**

```
<?php
Session_start();
Session_destroy();
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

?>
```

Your page_***_*____**

```
<a href="Logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. One should start the session before destroying it.

Answer (score 7):

Wrong code. you can use this code:

```
<?php if($_GET['logout']==1) session_destroy(); ?>
<a href="?logout=1">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

That code will already destroy the session before clicking the link, you should do it like this:

HTML Page:

```
<a href="sessiondestroy.php">Logout</a>
```

Sessiondestroy.php :

```
<?=session_start(); session_destroy(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

no its not valid...onclick is a client side event. you can do this instead.

```
     <a href="logout.php">logout</a>
```

and create a file called logout.php and include the session_destroy(); statement

```
       <?php
           session_destroy();

           //do other things... like redirect to a deafault/login page

         ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, its not logical to call server-side function from client-side, `onClick` is an event occurs at client side, so, it cant call `session_destroy()`because it's server-side (PHP Function) which is not available at client side

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do that. If you are focused on using the onClick action, you could simply use AJAX. First you would have to create ajax.php, which would look like this:

```
<?php
//AJAX dynamic callback
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    if($_GET['action'] == 'logout'){
        //destroy the session
        session_destroy();
        echo 'Logout success!';
        //redirect the user to a default web page using header
        header("location:http://example.com/");
    }
}
?>
```

Then you would want to create a javascript file that would tell ajax.php that you wanted to logout:

```
<script>
function logout()
 {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("Logoutbutton").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?action=logout",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>
```

Anyways, thanks for using StackOverflox, and please report back how it goes, or if you need additional help :)

TP

Comment: Most complicated logout I have ever, and I mean ever seen.